# Rails Post Request and Response

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, http-post

I'm not to familiar with HTTP so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I'm working on creating a backend rails api to store/validate users in my android app. What I'm trying to do is the first time the user logs in, I send a post request to my rails server to create a new user. After creating the user I'd like to send the app back the user's auth_token (which will then be used in the future to validate anything the user does).

So my question is this - can I send a string or json back after receiving a post request? If you can point me to a SO or guide, I'd appreciate that as well (I haven't found much so far).

If you can't do that, one other idea I had was to create the auth_token in the Android app, store it and send that to the server with the post requestion and set that as the user's auth_token.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post request will take you to the create method in the users_controller. After you create the user, you can do anything else that you want. The code should look something like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def create
    ...
    render json: ...
end
end
```